# Recursive method with OOJS

Tags: javascript, recursion

Given the following JS code:

+---------------------------------------------+

```
this.Element = function() {

this.twitch = function(e) {
        $(e).animate({
            height: "+=5"
        }, 1000, function() {
            $(e).animate({
                height: "-=5"
            }, 1000, function() {
            });
        });
    };

$(document).ready(function() {
    var footer = new this.Element();
    footer.twitch("#footer");
});
```

+---------------------------------------------+

How can I call the method "twitch()" recursively?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First error, `this` is refering to jQuery in this context `new this.Element();`

Fixed by:

```
this.Element = function( return this; ) {

this.Element.prototype.twitch = function(e) {
 var self = this;
        $(e).animate({
            height: "+=5"
        }, 1000, function() {
            $(e).animate({
                height: "-=5"
            }, 1000, function() {
               self.twitch(e);
            });
        });
    };

var self = this;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var footer = new this.Element();
    footer.twitch("#footer");
});
```